# limit some privileges for a user django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

from the admin site , localhost:8080/admin ,i created some custom user with limited privilege levels . I am building a system where each user is specified a single lab to work on .   I am satisfied with built in privilege level for users .But each time in drop down list , for every user i create , all lab names appear.

can i in some way customize the drop down list to assign specific user only a specific lab ?

my  models.py :

```
 from django.db import models

 # Create your models here.
 class LabName(models.Model):
 labsname=models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
 #room_number=models.CharField(max_length=3)
 def __unicode__(self):
 return self.labsname
 def isOwnedBy(self, user):
    return self.rental.isOwnedBy(user)
 class Meta:
    permissions = (
        ('view_task', 'View task'),
    )

  STAT=(('W','Working'),('N','Not Working'))
 class ComponentDescription(models.Model):
    lab_Title=models.ForeignKey('Labname')
    component_Name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    qty = models.IntegerField()
    purchased_Date = models.DateField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=STAT)
    to_Do = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True) 
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
    def isOwnedBy(self, user):
        return self.rental.isOwnedBy(user)
    class Meta:
         permissions = ( ('view_task', 'View task'),)




def __unicode__(self):
    return self.component_Name
```